# Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{t}$ and resulting improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

Could someone please explain how 
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx$$ diverges?
This is because the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{t}$ can be reduced to this integral which has to diverge. But the limit comparison test with $e^{-x}$ shows that the integral converges.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expanding $e^{-x}$ in a series might help you see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the second part of the question, to add to [carmichael561](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/314708/carmichael561)'s answer,

To use the limit comparison test with $e^{-x}$, we need
$$\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\le e^{-x}$$
throughout the interval over which integral takes place.

However, this is true only for $x\gt1$, and hence the test cannot be used.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is at zero:
$$ \int_0^1\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\;dx\geq \frac{1}{e}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x}=\infty $$
Therefore $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\;dx=\int_0^{1}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\;dx+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\;dx$ diverges.

Comment: Thank you. I had been missing that point for long.